# Drupal custom Views

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm looking for a way to create a custom Views on Drupal in order to recreate a private app store. Each item of the list will looks like this :
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/803200Thubnailapp.png

I created my Content type "Application" with the wanted fields. 
I read on forums that I have to create a View in order to do this but I don't know which Display format I have to chose and what I have to modify then in order to get this appearance for all my apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fields instead of display formats. Then add the fields (image, title, body and category) and control the appearance via CSS.

[This video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mQ9oj6ThGM) will help you get started. (it's the second of 10 videos in the series)

**Update**

If you would like to use a display format. You will need to configure the display for the teaser format. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENT_TYPE]/display/teaser`. Then, add the fields you want to display in the order you like, and click `Save`.

Then, format the output as you like using CSS.

Comment: There is no way to choose a display format and use CSS to custom the items of the list ?

Comment: Do you mean that you wanna achieve your goal using display format ?!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Using display format and CSS in order to have the appearance I want.

Comment: Then, format the output as you like using CSS. Where is the concerned CSS file ?

Comment: I looked in the style.css of my bartik theme but I found nothing on my content type. Is there an other CSS file ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: You define your CSS selectors and styles.

Comment: And how to tell to my view to apply my own css files ?

Comment: Just define your CSS selectors correctly, and your theme will load the CSS files with the selectors you defined.

Comment: I don't reallu know CSS. What does selectors mean ? Where I have to create my file ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm really trying to understand.

Comment: "Selectors" is what you type to target/select a specific HTML element on your page. Something like: `body #page-wrap .node`. In order to get the styling in the image you provided, kindly contact an CSS developer. And check this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp